# Grep for next blank line after line number

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I have a large file which contains tables of different tab separated data. The different tables are separated by a blank line.

I have the line number of the start of a particular table and I need to retrieve the whole table.

How can I use grep (or something similar) to get the line number of the next blank line after a specific line number?

Comment: you want to retrieve the table or just the next blank line nr??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sed` for this, this should do the trick:

```
sed -n '1,/^\s*$/p' file
```

Just replace the first number before the comma, in this case `1` with the line number, demo to print each table from a given line number:

```
$ cat file
one
two
three

five
six
seven

nine
ten
eleven

$ sed -n '1,/^\s*$/p' file
one
two
three

$ sed -n '5,/^\s*$/p' file
five
six
seven

$ sed -n '9,/^\s*$/p' file
nine
ten
eleven
```

Using the `-n` option to turn of default printing of every line and the `p` flag `sed` prints from the line number to the first line that matches the regexp where:

```
^     # Matches the start of the line
\s*   # Matches zero or more whitespace characters
$     # Matches the end of the line
```

Using the format `sed -n 'A,Bp'` where `A` and `B` can be either lines numbers or regular expression you can print subsections of files easily.

To print just the line number of the next blank line with `sed` do:

```
$ sed -n '1,/^\s*$/{=}' file | tail -1
4

$ sed -n '5,/^\s*$/{=}' file | tail -1
8

$ sed -n '9,/^\s*$/{=}' file | tail -1
12
```

Or just printing where all the blanks lines are

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*$/{=}' file
4
8
12
```

---

Getting the next blank line number with `awk` doesn't require using `tail`:

```
$ awk 'NR>=1 && /^\s*$/{print NR;exit}' file
4

$ awk 'NR>=5 && /^\s*$/{print NR;exit}' file
8

$ awk 'NR>=9 && /^\s*$/{print NR;exit}' file
12

$ awk '/^\s*$/{print NR}' file
4
8
12
```

If it makes it clearer for you, you can pass a variable in with `awk` using `-v`

```
$ awk -v start=1 'NR>=start && /^\s*$/{print NR;exit}' file
4

$ awk -v start=5 'NR>=start && /^\s*$/{print NR;exit}' file
8

$ awk -v start=9 'NR>=start && /^\s*$/{print NR;exit}' file
12
```

Comment: So where would the start line go?

Comment: @JacobTomlinson I have updated my answer, it should contain everything you need.

Comment: nice answer with explanations. just one comment, he mentioned "large file" personally I feel it would be better with `sed -n '5,$p; /^\s*$/q'` of course, if it make sense depending on how large his file is. but you could test with seq 99999999999|sed ...

Comment: @Kent Did you test? That won't work I think you mean `sed -n '5,${p;/^\s*$/q}'`, I understand what you saying but very much doubt any time will be saved with the method you tried.

Comment: Large file was probably a bit of an overstatement. It is around 4000 lines. But thank you for your answer it solved my problem quite elegantly.

Comment: @JacobTomlinson yes 4000 lines is no problem at all, happy to help!

Comment: @sudo_O important is you got my point. :) when I wrote the comment, I didn't test. sorry, but it works here. see http://minus.com/lPRjzsQmDMUaY  I think we can see the difference (delay) from the two lines.

Comment: How can I create a variable with the number of the empty line?

Answer (score 2):

Perl makes this simple. To extract all the lines from line 31 to the next blank line in *some_file*:

```
$ perl -wne 'print if 31 .. /^$/' some_file
```

Answer (score 0):

one way with awk:

```
awk -vs=$sta '{ok=NR>=s}ok&&!$0{exit;}ok&&$0'
```

`$sta` is a variable, which stores the start line number. if we test with sudo_O 's input example with start line nr=5, it looks like:

```
kent$  sta=5

kent$  echo "1
2
3

5
6
7

9
10
11"|awk -vs=$sta '{ok=NR>=s}ok&&!$0{exit;}ok&&$0'
5
6
7
```

note that sed's address will **include** the boundary ,which means, the empty line after the target table will also be printed out. This awk one-liner won't print it. well it depends on what you want in output.

**EDIT** in case you just want to get the next empty line number

```
awk -vs=$sta 'NR>=s&&!$0{print NR;exit;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in the below command 5 is your known line number of the table

```
perl -lne 'exit if(/^$/ && $.>5);if($.>=5){print}' your_file
```